# QPainter's setWorldTransform default behavior?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

The following code shows the window on the left (see image below). Nevertheless, uncommenting the line marked with `/*[identity transform]*/`, the window in the right is generated. As reported by qInfo() in the console output, nothing relevant for the coordinate transform seems to change.

Could anybody explain me the reason? I can't find it in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/coordsys.html).

```
class SomeItem : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
public:
    explicit SomeItem(const QRectF& rect, QGraphicsItem* parent = nullptr) :
        QGraphicsEllipseItem(rect,parent){}

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
               QWidget *widget)
    {
        QTransform tr;
        //painter->setWorldTransform(tr); /*[identity transform]*/
        qInfo() << painter->window().left() << painter->window().right()
                << painter->window().top() << painter->window().bottom();
        qInfo() << painter->viewport().left() << painter->viewport().right()
                << painter->viewport().top() << painter->viewport().bottom();
        qInfo() << painter->matrix().m11() << painter->matrix().m12()
                << painter->matrix().m21() << painter->matrix().m22();
        /* <--->*/
        QGraphicsEllipseItem::paint(painter,option,widget);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene ms;
    ms.setSceneRect(-20,-20,40,40);
    SomeItem* si = new SomeItem(QRectF(-10,-10,20,20));
    ms.addItem(si);
    QGraphicsView view(&ms);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Console output (for both cases):

```
0 197 0 97
0 197 0 97
1 0 0 1
```

[image: Result with commented line (left) and with uncommented line (right)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasoning on [Marek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55284111/10750537), I guess to have found a geometrical explaination. My fault was to inspect `painter->matrix()` rather than `painter->transform()`. Indeed, `Qmatrix` does not manage translation, while `painter->transform().m31()` and `painter->transform().m32()` do.

Substituting the following lines

```
qInfo() << painter->transform().m31() << painter->transform().m32();
```

in place of `/*<--->*/` provides console outputs for the two cases, respectively,

```
99 49
```

and

```
0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Paint method uses local coordinate system. This means that origin of painter is usually located at top left corner of `QGraphicsItem` (note this is base class for everything in QGraphicsScene). In case of `QGraphicsEllipseItem` it must be center of it.

Apparently this is implemented by transforming `QPainter` used by `QGraphicsView` widget when [void QWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) is processed.

Simply each `QGraphicsItem` in `QGraphicsScene` painted by `QGraphicsView` transform painter for its needs.

When you restore identity transformation, you got a painter in state which applies for `QGraphicsView` paint event. So it is top left corner of it.

You where lucky that nothing got broken since you are painting outside of [boundingRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I still don't get why I am painting outside of boundingRect; as far as I understand, if QPainter acts in local coordinate and tr is an identity transform, nothing is moved out of the boundingRect...could you explain me, please?